# How to count the number of words in HTML string?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a HTML string from a rich editor. I want to implement a feature in javascript that will count the number of words which are visible to user. The condition is the count should exclude the html tags and things which are not visible to the user in rich editor

Comment: An example of your input and expected output would help :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
  countWords = (richHtml) => {
    var regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig;
    var body = richHTML.split("><").join("> <");;
    var result = body.replace(regex, "");
    var arr = result.split(" ")
    var newArr = []
    arr.forEach((el, i) => {
      if (el != "" && el != "&nbsp;" && el != "&nbsp;&nbsp;" && el != "'") {
        newArr.push(el)
      }
    })
    return newArr.length
  }
```

Comment: Try [`DOMParser()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser). even faster and smarter way

Comment: Is it available in react native?

Comment: all js API's are available in react native